# Horror movie with teenagers in an abandoned asylum

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I watched a movie one night and I can't remember the title. The movie was about these teenagers who go into an old asylum at night and they can't seem to get out. They brought a dog with them too. I think it was white. The dog got turned inside out or like it's fur was ripped off so it was just muscle. The dog was covered in slime when the teenagers found it. And there was a hole in the wall and one teenager got stuck in the hole. And there was something in there with him but he got out before it was revealed.

In the end if the movie it is revealed that the thing causing the haunting and strange events was an old man. He was an asylum patient who was angry. He was trying to kill the teenagers and one teenager got killed by getting a chunk of wood shoved through his stomach. Another teenager died at the hands of a possessed clown thing. (Note: these events are not in order)

Comment: Welcome to M&TV! Thanks for the detailed question. Approximate year & country of origin can always help with ID, though I have a good match for you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like [Boo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0385560/combined) from 2005. The floating clown, the dead dog, the hole in the wall, it's all there.

> The friends Emmett, Freddy, Marie, Kevin and his reluctant girlfriend Jessie decide to spend the Halloween night in an abandoned hospital. Meanwhile, the younger Allan meets the old friend of his father Arlo Ray Baines and asks him to help to find his vanished sister Meg in the same spot. The two groups meet each other in the mental institution section on the haunted third floor and they find that they are trapped in the place. Jessie has visions from the past and discovers that the ghost of Jacob, a former patient that raped a little girl and burned the hospital, is trying to escape possessing their bodies that melt down with his evil spirit.

Here's the trailer: